# Tax for foreign money received thru PayPal in india

Tags: income-tax, india, international, paypal, transfer

Is there any tax in India for money received thru PayPal to my company's current account from my international clients?

Answer (score 1):

Tax is due in India as you offered services from India.

So whether the International Client pays via Credit Card, Bank Transfer, Paypal or any other means is not relevant. Even if the International Client pays you in a account outside India; it is still taxable in India.

Answer (score -2):

there is no tax for receiving money from outside of india paypal just take their charges only